# vscode cannot place breakpoints (Python)

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I can't place breakpoints or see the option to place them when I hover my mouse over the break point margin.

I think this has something to do with the options in the 'break point' section of the debug window in the bottom left where there are the options:

- All exceptions & -Uncaught exceptions. I remember there being a third option but this is no longer there.

If anyone have any idea how this can be fixed it would be much appreciated :)

Comment: Check the top of the side bar, in the drop-down list next to the (triangular) 'Play' button, does it say 'No Configurations' or similar? If so, you may need to click the adjacent 'gear' icon to configure a launch.json file for your project.

Comment: The drop down menu beside the debug play button is set to 'Python' , and there has been a launch.json file created

Comment: I've now tried reinstalling cscode, aswell as python within it but neither has worked :/ if someone knows a fix , let me know ! thx